# Update query with max(date) in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

There are two tables named `emp` and `ct1`
Requirement is to get max(hiredate) from `emp` and update it to `ct1` table.

used :

```
Update ct1 
set session_date=(select max(hiredate)from emp) 
where table_name='src1';
```

table content

```
emp 
name hiredate
A    12-12-2004
B    14-08-2000

ct1 table
table_name session_date
SRC1          null
SRC2          null
```

Comment: there is no hiredate column in emp table given above. please correct

Comment: In tables names as `emp` and `ct1` only you mention in quesry as `table_name=src1`. once see and correct it

Comment: Your update statement works when there is a row in the table which matches `where table_name='SRC1'`.  So there must be something odd in your set-up.  What is the datatype of `ct1.table_name` ?

Comment: @APC Datatype for table_name is varchar2

Comment: Please don't edit your question to make it look as though there was no error. Changing the case of `'src1'` to `'SRC'` makes the accepted answer look pointless. I've rolled it back. In future, please only edit your question to add necessary information. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis : WinterBash should include a police helmet to reward your endeavours :)

Comment: @APC: only if I can have a baton and a Taser too. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you shoud use tha uppercase for the where condition .. otherwise don't match

```
Update ct1 
set (session_date) = (select max(hiredate)from emp )
where table_name='SRC1'
and session_data is null;
```

Comment: i used SRC1 in capitals in database. but it is not working.

Comment: [Error] Execution (14: 20): ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: by using : select max(hiredate) from emp  i am getting the max date and when i am directly assing  the value instead of select max(hiredate) it is updating the ct1 table .

Comment: In which context you are using thei query .. in a server programm? in a script ?

Comment: The query is to be  used  in  PreSQL query in informatica source Qualifier

Comment: Thanks , after dropping the table and creating again the query is working fine.